# C++ 2010 builder show hint all time

Tags: ide, c++builder, hint

How to in c++ 2010 builder show hint all the time when is code write?
For example if I try to use command MessageBox, I start to type message and press control+space, that will be show up list of functions which have first letter same, and after that I press enter on which function I like and that give me a yellow hint, everything is ok therefore I press backspace or make error in spelling that hint then disappear. So my question is how to force that hint message to stay guiding me all the time (like in Visual studio)?

Answer (score 0):

Place cursor after '(' ans press Ctrl+Shift+Space to redisplay hint.